# Message / confirm dialog

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a need for a confirm message box from a button click, but only on some conditions. I am cheking two values on the aspx.page, and if one is higher than another, I need a confirmation from the user. Are there any ( simple) way of doing this ? I have been reading about javascript and alert messages, but I cant seem to figure out this one....
I am using RadStudio 2007, .net application.

Any help are appriciated.
Anja

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript provides what you need with the confirm function. This displays a confirmation box allowing the user to 'OK' or 'Cancel'.
An example function based on what you require:

```
function FormSubmit() {
    var value1 = document.getElementById("Textbox1").value;
    var value2 = document.getElementById("Textbox2").value;
    if (value1 > value2) {
        return Boolean(confirm("Are you sure?"));
    }
}
```

This function can now be added to the buttons `onclick` method

```
<input type="Button" value="Submit" onclick="return FormSubmit()" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a confirm message example in javascript :

```
<a href="deleteUser.aspx?id=231" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete user ?')">Delete User</a>
```

[Some Other Helpful Examples](http://www.michael-thomas.com/tech/javascript/ex_confirm.htm)